# Pass Subquery as function parameter

Tags: mysql

How to function subquery as a function parameter

```
 select  get_feeTypeamount(SELECT ftp.type_plan_id 
                 FROM tbl_fee_type_plan ftp
       WHERE ftp.type_plan_id=17) as total_amount
```

Comment: you code  have no sense try explain better ..

Comment: If you know the query that should be passed why not use it inside your function? There is no way of doing that the way you asked. Only way is to pass the query as string and dynamically execute it inside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a sub-query. Just apply the function to the `ftp.type_plan_id` column in your `SELECT`.

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT get_feeTypeamount(ftp.type_plan_id) as total_amount 
FROM tbl_fee_type_plan ftp
WHERE ftp.type_plan_id=17
```